# Pausing nodes in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CocosBuilder file that I'm reading in and its animating fine but when i try to call

```
[node pauseSchedulerAndActions];
```

it doesn't seem to have any effect on the node. I'm not sure if its something to do with the timeline that I have to stop it or something? I've tried to go through every child node as well to make sure everything was paused and still nothing.

```
- (void)stopAllLayerAnimations:(CCNode*)node {

  for (CCNode* childNode in [node children]) {

    [self stopAllLayerAnimations:childNode];
  }
  [node pauseSchedulerAndActions];
}
```

and i know calling

```
[node stopAllActions];
```

removes the actions from the action list which is not what I want.

if anyone has any advice on how to get this working it would be great!

Comment: This should work. What do you expect to happen to the node, and what is happening?

Comment: i would like it stop animating and then later resume it. but for some reason it continues to animate after the call stated above